# Calculating average between different start and end time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given a dataframe df of start "T_S" and end times "T_E", I would like to calcule the average value for the value Q from another panda dataframe for each row of df between those times.

```
df=pandas.DataFrame({'T_S':[30-09-2022  14:11:36, 30-09-2022  14:14:52, 30-09-2022  14:18:30],'T_E':[30-09-2022  14:14:22, 30-09-2022  14:18:20, 30-09-2022  14:21:11]})
```

The data table to calculate the average of the Q value is like this one:

```
dQ=pandas.DataFrame({'T':[2022-09-29 15:37:03, 2022-09-29 15:37:04  ,2022-09-29 15:37:05], 'Q':[1,5,6]})
```

I have tried several codes with between_time and group_by but it throws errors each time. I guess I am stuck in something easy but couldn't find a way out.

Any help, please ;)

Thanks,

Comment: No Images, please post data as a code (preferably) or text.

Comment: Sorry Naveed, I have put the code instead, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

import pandas as pd

```
## Create a sample time-value table (dQ in your case)
dQ = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               'value': [10.5, 20.3, 15.8, 18.6, 22.1]})

## Create a sample time1-time2 table (df in your case)
time_ranges = pd.DataFrame({'time1': [2, 4],
                        'time2': [3, 5]})

## Join the two tables based on the time column
merged_dQ = pd.merge(dQ, time_ranges, how='inner', on='time')

## Filter the rows where time is between time1 and time2
filtered_dQ = merged_dQ[(merged_dQ['time'] >= merged_dQ['time1']) & (merged_dQ['time'] <= merged_dQ['time2'])]

## Calculate the average of the values in the filtered table
avg_value = filtered_dQ['value'].mean()

print(avg_value)
```